# Cast Google Analytics Value to variable

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I am using GoogleAnalytics Embed API in order to create a custom analytics dashboard.

Currently my code looks like this:

My problem is that I am trying to use the variable `CurrentUsers` in other calculations.

Here's my code

```
var CurrentUsers; // declared globally

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    var CurrentVisitorsData = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
        query: {
            ids: 'ga:xxxxxx',
            metrics: 'ga:users',
            'start-date': '7daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday'
        }
    });

    CurrentVisitorsData.on('success', function(response) {

        CurrentUsers = response.totalsForAllResults['ga:users'];
        console.log (CurrentUsers); //this displays the correct number of current users
    });

    CurrentVisitorsData.execute();

    console.log (currentUsers); // This one returns Uncaught ReferenceError: CurrentUsrs is not defined

});
```

So within the response function the variable works, but after it does not. I need to use multiple variables and perform operations on them, so I can't do what I need to do in the response function.

Any idea how I can access that value outside of the success function?

Answer (score 0):

1. You declare currentUsers, not CurrentUsers so it throws an error.
2. CurrentVisitorsData.on(...) is an asynchronous operation. What does it mean? When you execute `console.log(CurrentUsers);` CurrentUsers is undefined, because has no value yet. You should pass it to function or with callback.

=

```
function onResponseLoad(CurrentUsers){
  //do something with it
  console.log(CurrentUsers);
}

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
  var CurrentUsers;
  var CurrentVisitorsData = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query: {
      ids: 'ga:xxxxxx',
        metrics: 'ga:users',
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday'
      }
  });

  CurrentVisitorsData.on('success', function(response) {
    CurrentUsers = response.totalsForAllResults['ga:users'];
    onResponseLoad(CurrentUsers);
  });

  CurrentVisitorsData.execute();
});
```

or using IIFE and Promises (maybe code looks better):

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
  var CurrentUsers;

  var CurrentVisitorsData = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
      query: {
        ids: 'ga:xxxxxx',
        metrics: 'ga:users',
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday'
      }
    });

    (function getResponse(){
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        CurrentVisitorsData.on('success', function(response) {
          CurrentUsers = response.totalsForAllResults['ga:users'];
          resolve(CurrentUsers);
        });
      })
    })()
    .then(function(CurrentUsers){
      console.log(CurrentUsers);

    });

    CurrentVisitorsData.execute();
});
```